# How to do CSS on hover targeting styles of a selector with two element names

Tags: css

I know you can change the style of a selector on hover of another selector, but it doesn't work when the selector you need to change uses two element names like this:

**Doesn't work.** Anyway to make this work with just CSS?

```
.menu-btn:hover .menu-btn span  {
    /*styles*/
}
```

**Works**

```
.menu-btn:hover span  {
     /*styles*/
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you need exactly?

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-btn:hover span, .menu-btn span  {
/*styles*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a coma between .menu-btn:hover span and .menu-btn span. This should probably work if I understood your question correctly.

```
.menu-btn:hover span, .menu-btn span  {
    //code;
}
```